# Pandas groupbyObject to DataFrame to merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `DataFrame` they have the same index.

Dataframe 1 let's call this 'click' Has multiple lines with the same value for each index. Something like this:

[image]

DataFrame 2: Should has only one line for each index, let's call it 'train_data'. Something like this:

[image]

I tryed to group by `DataFrame 1`and then add the values to my DataFrame 2 like this:

```
click_gb = click.groupby('COLUMN_WHAT_I_NEED')
train_data['COLUMN_WHAT_I_NEED'] = click_gb['COLUMN_WHAT_I_NEED']
```

But, it's added to DataFrame 2 every rows that belongs to that index in DataFrame 1. Like this:

[image]

Help me please, how can I solve this.

Sorry it wasn't clear: here comes a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {
    'idx': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'what_i_need': ['Some_Value','Some_Value','Some_Value','Other_Value','Other_Value','Other_Value'],
    'other_column' : ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
}
data2 = {
    'idx': [1,2],
    'what_i_need': ['Here_I_should_add_the_value','Here_I_should_add_the_value']        
}
click_df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
train_df = pd.DataFrame(data2)
click_df = click_df.set_index('idx')
train_df = train_df.set_index('idx')

print('My dataframes after setting index:')
print(click_df.head())
print(train_df.head())

click_df_gr = click_df.groupby('what_i_need')
print('Group by object:')
print(click_df_gr.head())

train_df['what_i_need'] = click_df_gr['what_i_need']
print('this is how final result looks like:')
print(train_df.head())
```

this is the output:

```
My dataframes after setting index:
     what_i_need other_column
idx                          
1     Some_Value            1
1     Some_Value            2
1     Some_Value            3
2    Other_Value            4
2    Other_Value            5
                     what_i_need
idx                             
1    Here_I_should_add_the_value
2    Here_I_should_add_the_value
Group by object:
     what_i_need other_column
idx                          
1     Some_Value            1
1     Some_Value            2
1     Some_Value            3
2    Other_Value            4
2    Other_Value            5
2    Other_Value            6
this is how final result looks like:
                                           what_i_need
idx                                                   
1    (Other_Value, [Other_Value, Other_Value, Other...
2    (Some_Value, [Some_Value, Some_Value, Some_Val...
```

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you to use actual code and not images. Additionally, give us an example of your desired output, please!

Comment: I can copy you here the actual DataFrames but it would look like exactly the same the images I posted. And the desired output would be also same. :(

Comment: The difference is that we can copy paste your code and play with it instead of building it ourselves from scratch

Comment: As it is, this question remains unclear

Comment: Sorry, i try to create a sample code for you.

Answer (score 2):

if you're sure the DataFrame1 has smae value for each index, why don't you use drop_duplicates? It would help you check that fact. You may create a merge_index column, as index should be column that stores unique values.
For example :

```
import pandas as pa

data1 = {
    'idx': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
    'what_i_need': ['Some_Value','Some_Value','Some_Value','Other_Value','Other_Value','Other_Value']        
}

data2 = {
    'idx': [1,2],
    'what_i_need': ['Here_I_should_add_the_value','Here_I_should_add_the_value']        
}

click_df = pa.DataFrame(data1)
train_df = pa.DataFrame(data2)

print(click_df)
print(train_df)

   idx  what_i_need
0    1   Some_Value
1    1   Some_Value
2    1   Some_Value
3    2  Other_Value
4    2  Other_Value
5    2  Other_Value
   idx                  what_i_need
0    1  Here_I_should_add_the_value
1    2  Here_I_should_add_the_value
```

Now try :

```
click_df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print(click_df)
   idx  what_i_need
0    1   Some_Value
3    2  Other_Value
```

Then you can do :

```
train_df = train_df.merge(click_df, how='inner', on='idx', suffixes=('_train','_click'))
train_df.drop(columns=['what_i_need_train'], inplace=True)
print(train_df)
   idx what_i_need_click
0    1        Some_Value
1    2       Other_Value
```

Comment: it would be good, but there are also other columns in my dataframe with different values. Sorry, i will update my question because my question is unclear.

Comment: No problem, but I think the code would work with other columns, you might just need to rename some of them. Have a nice day.

Comment: I tryed it and it's not working. I have 22 millions record in my click Dataframe, and after dropping duplicates will be only 6 rows. :(

Comment: I think it is because you have another index like me. I cannot remove the index from my dataframes.

Comment: Ok, but then you can use your index to create another column, like this click_df['idx'] = click_df.index.values before drop_duplicates

Comment: I believe there may be another solution with groupby('what_i_need') but it would be much more complicated.

Comment: sorry, i try to do what you wrote in your answer but it's not working for me i got this error: 
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: i'm doing this: I create another dataframe from datafame 1 where i chose only what_i_need column. After i reset the index, because without reseting the index there would be only six distinct row. After reseting the index i run drop duplicates and after i set the index. When i try to run this : df_train['what_i_need'] = df_click['what_i_need']

Comment: Then maybe you can try to build the new dataframe with two columns, first one would be idx, having click_df index values, second one would be the 'what_i_need' column.

Comment: i can't becuase i have to leave the index in my train_df, and i have many many columns in that dataframe. So i cannot build new df. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want only 1 value per row in DF2, so this also assumes that some_value is the same every time:

Why not drop the duplicate values:

```
train_data['COLUMN_WHAT_I_NEED'] = click_gb['COLUMN_WHAT_I_NEED'].drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thank you, but click_gb is a SeriesGroupBy object here, and doesn't have drop_duplicates: AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'drop_duplicates' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method